# Combine two filter actions

Tags: gmail

I use filters to organise emails into 'folders'. eg all emails to/from my children go into my 'Children' folder. 
I use a filter to add a 'Children' label to outgoing emails to them and a separate filter to add the 'Children' label to any received emails from them so that any email I send to them or they send to me all finish up in the same folder.
Does anyone know how to combine these two actions into one filter?
Currently I have two filters every time I send/receive emails that I need to put into the same folder, eg to/from specific companies, forums, etc. etc.?

Comment: How are you using a filter to label outgoing mail? Gmail only labels incoming messages.

Comment: Hi. No, gmail also labels outgoing mail. Just click the down arrow in the search box to open the 'Show search options' criteria box and enter an email address in the 'To' field. Complete the remaining fields as appropriate and wallah, all email to that address will be labelled in accordance with your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something similar with my own kids, although I have labels for each of them.

You should be able to do something like this:

```
Has the words: (to:myfavoritechild@gmail.com OR from:myfavoritechild@gmail.com)
```

Note that `OR` needs to be in all-caps for it to be recognized properly.

You can string several of these together like so:

```
Has the words: (to:myfavoritechild@gmail.com OR from:myfavoritechild@gmail.com) OR (to:my2ndfave@gmail.com OR from:my2ndfave@gmail.com) OR (to:cinderella@gmail.com OR from:cinderella@gmail.com)
```

There's a lot of space, but not an infinite amount, so I don't know how many times you can do that. I generally prefer not to do that.

Comment: My longest query has 41 'OR' statements in it and I've never had any problems so it seems long enough to cater for anything anyone can throw at it.